# Expression to test for one or more spaces in VBA to find matches in Excel cells

Tags: regex, vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to use regular expressions in a macro for an Excel document.

Here is what I have so far:

```
dim regex
regex.pattern = "\s+"
for p = 3 to totalparamcount
    if (regex.test(Worksheets("table").Cells(p,1)) then
        msgbox ("blah blah")
    end if
next
```

The pattern I am trying to match is one or more spaces, tabs, newlines, which I saw is denoted by `"\s"`.

The line '`if (regex.test(Worksheets("table").Cells(p,1)) then`' is getting this error:

```
Run-time error '424':

Object required
```

I am using VBA 7.0 in Excel.

Comment: might be better asked on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the regexp object, ie

```
Dim regex
Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
regex.Pattern = "\s+"
```