# Loop and replace two or more spaces with only one

Tags: excel, vba

I want to replace all multiple spaces in cells in my range `A1:K1000`. So if 2 or more spaces, then replace them with one space `" "`.

My current code replaces spaces that are `"  "` (2) spaces. How to adjust it to work with 2 or more spaces? So it will handle cases like `"   "`, `"   "`, `"       "` etc.

Here is my code:

```
Sub RemoveSpaces()

Dim r1 As Range
Set r1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K1000") 
r1.Replace _
      What:=Space(2), _
      Replacement:=" ", _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      MatchCase:=True
Set r1 = r1.Find(What:=Space(2))
If Not r1 Is Nothing Then
   Call RemoveSpaces
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Loop the cells and use `Application.Trim`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to remove 'extra' spaces (more than 1) from a large range of cells using VBA for excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768072/fastest-way-to-remove-extra-spaces-more-than-1-from-a-large-range-of-cells-u)

Comment: See the recursive approach in the dupe target. Or adjust one of the other answers. In any case, this has been tried before, and multiple solutions have been proposed.

Comment: Note - change `Call RemoveSpaces_3` to `RemoveSpaces` to recurse (`Call` is deprecated too).

Comment: Looks like duplicate but actually in provided link there is only particular case covered with replace. I already have this kind of code that is covering case with two spaces. However I need to remove all multiple spaces -> two and more. Scott Craner solution looks good. I have to try it

Comment: Where are these spaces? i.e. beginning of the text or end? or can be either or both?

Comment: They can be in the begging and at the end, sometimes they are between the words

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777419/expression-to-test-for-one-or-more-spaces-in-vba-to-find-matches-in-excel-cells)

Comment: The *recursive* answer in the dupe handles more than two spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to loop cells:

[image]

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3")
rng.Value = Application.Trim(rng)

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This should probably be an answer to the dupe target too, this is great.

Comment: I don't know if it should be posted there, but at an initial glance it seems better than the accepted answer. Note, this is definitely a dupe, despite claims to the contrary :)

Comment: Although... Replace might be better if formulas are in involved, I still need to test.

Comment: My comment was that it overwrites formulas with values... `="This     is     a    test"` gets converted to text :( Just a caveat.

Comment: @BigBen, I see. Agreed! Either way, my answer is up there now too. Will put a note down, that it will overwrite formula results with it's value

Answer (score 0):

So from Scott Craner comment, solution to this question seems to be:

```
Sub RemoveSpaces()

    Dim A As Range

    Set A = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K1000") 

    For Each cell In A
    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell)
    Next

End Sub
```